# Iterating over Java ArrayList using JSTL/EL

Tags: java, html, jstl, el

trying to print out to my html document a list of book titles.

```
    <c:forEach items="${reservedItems}" var="item"> 
                                <<c:out value="${item.title}" />
                           </c:forEach>
```

But this isn't printing anything to my html page?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters but there is an extra `<` in line `<<c:out value="${item.title}" />`

Comment: Is your list empty? Have you debugged to see if it contains anything?

Comment: list has items, we have the data set for it

Comment: Can you do empty check and using c:if and see JSP getting non-empty list/

Comment: Did a check, appears to be a populated list.

Comment: Do the `item` objects have a method called `getTitle()`?

Comment: Yes, they do have getters for the title

Comment: Tested syntax error - no fix

Comment: Is the getter called `getTitle()`? Or something else?

Comment: it is called getTitle()

Comment: Do you have the JSTL imported in your page? Check the source code of your HTML page, whether your JSP code is printed there verbatim.